# Python Pandas DataFrame - Cannot plot bars and lines on the same axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I might be doing something wrong but I'm struggling to achieve the below:

```
# plot bars and lines in the same figure, sharing both x and y axes.
df = some DataFrame with multiple columns
_, ax = plt.subplots()
df[col1].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
df[col2].plot(ax=ax, marker='o', ls='-')
ax.legend(loc='best')
```

I expected to see a chart with **both** some bars and a line. However, what I end up with is only the line for `df[col2]`, **the bars from `df[col1]` are just not on the chart**. Whatever is before `df[col2]` seem to have been overwritten.

I got around this with:

```
df[col1].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, label=bar_labels)
ax.plot(df[col2], marker='o', ls='-', label=line_labels)
ax.legend(loc='best')
```

However, this isn't perfect as I had to use `label` tags otherwise legends will not included items for `df[col2]`...

**Anyone out there has a more elegant solution to make both bars and lines show up?**

** Edit ** 
Thanks to @DizietAsahi - Found out that this is a problem with DatetimeIndex as x-values. Filed the following at Pandas:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10761#issuecomment-128671523

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. your code works for me (OSX; panda version:  0.16.2; matplotlib version:  1.4.3)

Comment: @DizietAsahi I'm running Anaconda 2.3, Windows 7 64-bit. Running this in an ipython notebook with `%matplotlib inline`. sorry should have clarified.

Comment: "Thanks to @DizietAsahi - Found out that this is a problem with DatetimeIndex as x-values." - Give them an upvote, then ;)  On a serious note - rather than putting the edit in the question - it would be better to write your own answer referencing DizietAsahi answer and accept it, or edit the link to pandas issue you raised into his answer.  Otherwise, the question shows as unanswered.  [Self answers](stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) are perfectly fine on here.

Comment: @JRichardSnape - Done! thanks for the tip. I thought I already upvoted his answer!

Answer (score 6):

I wonder if your problem is related to the `hold` state of your plot...

This works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((10,2)), columns=['col1', 'col2'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.hold(True)
df['col1'].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
df['col2'].plot(ax=ax, marker='o', ls='-')
ax.legend(loc='best')
```

[image]

This only shows the line and not the bar plot

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((10,2)), columns=['col1', 'col2'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.hold(False)
df['col1'].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
df['col2'].plot(ax=ax, marker='o', ls='-')
ax.legend(loc='best')
```

[image]

Comment: tried this but didn't solve my problem. Let me do some more tests and come back, thanks!

Comment: Found out why I couldn't get your results. The issue happens when I have a DatetimeIndex for the data frame. for your code, if you try: `drange = pd.date_range(start='2015-07-01', end='2015-07-10', freq='D'); df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random_sample((10, 3)), index=drange, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']);`  It will reproduce my problem if you plot it with your code above even with `plt.hold(True)`..

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @DizietAsahi - Found out that this is a problem with DatetimeIndex as x-values. Integer values work with @DizietAsahi's code above.

Filed the following at Pandas:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10761#issuecomment-128671523

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with using DatetimeIndex as my x-values. I couldn't get the hack at [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10761#issuecomment-128671523) to work, using Jupyter Notebook Version 4.2.0 with Python 2.7.11. I'm grouping two columns by month to plot as bars, then overlaying raw values as a line graph.

My solution is to use matplotlib to plot the bar charts and the line, this was the only way I could get it to work.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', index_col='Date')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10)) 
ax.hold(True)
g = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("M"))
width=10

ax.bar(g.sum().index, g['Money Out'].sum(),width=width, color='r',label='Money Out')
ax.bar(g.sum().index, g['Money in'].sum(),width=-width,color='g', label='Money In')
ax.plot(df[['Balance']], color='black', lw=1, ls='-',label='Balance')  

ax.legend(loc='best')
```

[image]